# removing an item from an array in Vuex

Tags: vuex

I am just starting using Vuex but am having a problem (and this could be some clueless syntax error on my part). I have a user with liked_items and have a network call that is to unlike an item.

```
mutations: {
SET_TOGGLE_LIKED: (state, { global_id }) => {
  alert('here is global_id: ' + global_id)
 state.user.liked_items.find((obj,i) => {
   if(obj.global_id === global_id){ // no global_id
      console.log('that exists at i: ' + i + ' with length: ' + state.user.liked_items.length)
      state.user.liked_items.splice(i, 1)
      console.log('that exists at i: ' + state.user.liked_items.length)
   }else{
     console.log('that doesnot exist!')
   }
 })
}
```

The problem I'm having is that after removing an item from the liked_items list, that seems to get recalled and I get an error that global_id does not exist on undefined.

I am able to fix by having:

```
 state.user.liked_items.find((obj,i) => {
   if(obj){
     if(obj.global_id === global_id){
```

but why do I need to check for the existence of `obj` here?

Answer (score 16):

We can also use **map** to get the `index` of the object in a **store array** and remove it using:

**Mutation**

```js
REMOVE_OBJECT_FROM_ARRAY: (state, payload) => {
    const i = state.someArrayofObjects.map(item => item.id).indexOf(payload.id);
    state.someArrayofObjects.splice(i, 1);
  }
```

Here, the `id` is the id passed with the payload to the `MUTATION`, we can also pass only the `id` as the whole `payload`. In that case, we can do something like:

```js
REMOVE_OBJECT_FROM_ARRAY: (state, payload) => {
    const i = state.someArrayofObjects.map(item => item.id).indexOf(payload);
    state.someArrayofObjects.splice(i, 1);
  }
```

Comment: Thanks, but why not use `findIndex(item => item.id === payload)`?

Comment: Thank you very much. why doesn't this work with the filter?

Comment: Thank you for this answer, we should add a condition to check if the index exists to avoid deleting all items like this `if (i != -1) {
state.someArrayofObjects.splice(removeIndex, 1); }`

Comment: This doesn't answer the question: `why do I need to check for the existence of obj here?`

Comment: you are looking for the index of the object in order to delete it and you are not check for existence of the object.

Answer (score 2):

If you have `undefined` as elements of the `liked_items` array, you'll get `obj` as `undefined` sometimes.

You could simplify your `if` as below, though:

```
 state.user.liked_items.find((obj,i) => {
   if(obj && obj.global_id === global_id){
```

Or could pre-filter the array to keep only non-`undefined` values:

```
 state.user.liked_items.filter(o => o).find((obj,i) => {
   if(obj.global_id === global_id){
```

Answer (score -2):

You can use the following mutation, it uses the `splice` from Javascript array methods.

```
deleteElement: function(state.element) {
  state.myArray.splice(this.events.indexOf(element), 1);
}
```

If you know the index of the element, it becomes (obviously):

```
deleteElement: function(state,elementIndex) {
  state.myArray.splice(elementIndex, 1);
}
```

"1" is the number of elements to remove, starting from elementIndex

Comment: The question is `why do I need to check for the existence of obj here?`